# Code Navigation in yiiclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, yii

I used yiiclipse plugin in my php project building. I installed it in my eclipse (with PDT). The code completion works nice. And then I found its code navigation introducing in the web site of yiiclipse. But I can't find where to trigger these features in my eclipse. Could anyone told me where or how to get this feature work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly for future visitors:

Install [yiiclipse](http://yiiclipse.maziarz.org/). In PHP Explorer in Eclipse, right click project name->Configure->Toggle Yii Support. This should automatically add the following to your .project file (present in your root folder):

```
<buildSpec>
    ...
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.maziarz.yiiclipse.builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>

<natures>
    <nature>org.maziarz.yiiclipse.nature</nature>
    ...
</natures>
```

Then, right click on project again->Properties->PHP Include Path->Libraries->Add External Source Folder. Here select the folder where you installed the yii framework.